# Extracting units (with or without numerical quantities) from text data

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-science

I am trying to process texts containing technical data and extract any units used in text.

I have investigated a several Python libraries for this purpose, but most don't seem able to extract units when there is no associated number. For instance, I'd like to find 'Hz' (or some form of it) from the sentence 'All frequencies will be reported in Hz.'

Quantulum and grobid-quantities are not designed to deal with such cases, and tests indicate that they don't find units when there is no associated numerical quantity or qualifier. Other packages like pint seemed designed for calculation rather than NLP.

Are there other packages that would work?

I'd also be fine with a look-up solution; just matching to some extensive list of units and their various abbreviations, but I haven't been able to find such a list. Pointers to one if it exists would be appreciated. There must be such lists underlying existing unit-management packages, but I'm not sure how to get to them.

Comment: If you don't have context, it will be very hard to find units without number unless you know what you are searching, for instance "A" can be used for Ampere but it is also an English word. What kind of unit do you have?

Comment: That's good point, @Laurent. I am aware that there will almost inevitably be false positives, but I have some preprocessing steps which should greatly reduce the amount of text to be searched (e.g. reduce to scanning a paragraph or two instead of many multi-page files) and thus mitigate the false positives. I'm looking for several types of units -- time, length, power, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point: you can use a regular expression.

For instance:

```py
import re

para = """
This long text may contains units like kg, W, s, m.
"""

print(
    re.findall(
        r"\b(?:dag|dam|daL|min|sec|rad|deg|bar|mol|kg|hg|dg|cg|mg|\xb5g"
        r"|km|hm|dm|cm|mm|\xb5m|kL|hL|dL|cL|mL|\xb5L|ms|\xb0C|\xb0F"
        r"|sr|Pa|dB|eV|Bq|Ci|Gy|rd|Sv|cd|lm|lx|Gs|Mx|Wb|F|g|m|L|s|h"
        r"|K|B|N|W|J|A|V|H|C|T)\b",
        para,
        flags=re.DOTALL,
    )
)
```

You get:

```
['kg', 'W', 's', 'm']
```

But you may have false positive.

A more complex Regex is necessary to match "kW.m^{-1}" for instance.

**EDIT**

An example of "more complex Regex" can be the GPS position:

```py
GPS_COORD_REGEX = (
    r"(?:"
    r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*°"  # group 1
    r"\s*"
    r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*['’\u2032]"  # group 2
    r"(?:\s*"
    r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*(?:[»«“”\u2033]|['’\u2032]{2}))?"  # group 3
    r")"
)
```

Another exemple: match m^2, cm^2, etc. :

```py
regex=r"\b(km|hm|dam|m|dm|cm|mm|µm)([23])\b"
```